# How to find biggest price using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have to do such a thing:

From the list of prices (writed as a text: 10.00 USD), find the heighest price.
I have the list as:

```
<ul>
    <li>29.99 USD</li>
    <li>129.00 USD</li>
    <li>40.00 USD</li>
    <li>229.99 USD</li>
    <li>30.00 USD</li>
</ul>
```

How to save as variable the highest value? I understand that I need to replace text on mathematical value (cut off the last four characters) and then see who is the greatest. How to do it?

Comment: So you're saying that you want to round the value to the nearest whole number and then find the highest, is that right? Also please post the code you've attempted yourself. SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Please share your approach or piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method get all parsed numbers array and then get max value from the array using [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)  with [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method.

```js
console.log(
  Math.max.apply(Math, $('ul li').map(function() {
    return Number($(this).text().replace(/[^\d.]+/g, '')); // parse number after removing any non-digit char
  }).get())
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>29.99 USD</li>
  <li>129.00 USD</li>
  <li>40.00 USD</li>
  <li>229.99 USD</li>
  <li>30.00 USD</li>
</ul>
```